# Docker Network not Found

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network

In our team, we are currently transitioning to Docker to deploy everything on our server.

We are using Docker Swarm and multiple (10+) compose files defining plenty (20+) of services. Everything works beautifully so far, except when we take down our stack using `docker stack rm <name>` (and redeploy using `docker stack deploy <options> <name>`): about every second time, we get the following error:

```
Failed to remove network <id>: Error response from daemon: network <id> not foundFailed to remove some resources from stack: <name>
```

When using `docker network ls`, the network is indeed not removed, however, `docker network rm <id>` always results in the following:

```
Error response from daemon: network <id> not found
```

What makes that even more strange is the fact that `docker network inspect <id>` returns a normal output. The networks are always `overlay` networks that are created with the compose files used to deploy our stack. Currently, we only have a single node in our Swarm.

Our current "workaround" is to restart Docker (which resolves the issue), but that is not a viable solution in a production environment. Leaving the swarm and joining it again does not resolve the issue either.

At first, we thought that this issue is related to Docker for Mac only (as we first encountered the issue on local machines), however, the same issue arises on Debian Stretch. In both cases, we use the latest Docker distribution available.

I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: Did you check to see if all the containers using this network are not running? the stack rm issues the command to delete all the services immediately but the containers themselves takes a bit of time. Also, are the networks has any configurations? IPAM, specific drivers?

Answer (score 289):

If you are attempting to add a container to an existing network that no longer exists, then you can use `docker-compose up --force-recreate`. I found this [GitHub issues comment](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5745#issuecomment-370031631) to be a helpful overview.

Comment: This did the trick for me!

Comment: This did not resolve the issue on Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086.

Comment: but still, does this command make every service build again and not use the cache? if yes, is there any way to just remove the old network?

Answer (score 33):

You can always use `docker system prune -a` to get rid of the old network.  This will not delete your volumes.
It will take longer to `docker-compose up --build -d` the next time, but it will get you past your current problem.

Comment: `docker system prune -a` will remove all your existing images and containers. DO NOT USE!

Comment: Indeed. Not sure what the additional `-a` is usefull for, because it does the same without it.

Comment: My problem fixed without -a flag

Comment: `-a` also removes tagged images which are not in use. https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/#prune-images

Answer (score 21):

After using the docker prune command, I was unable to launch the docker container on a network.

The following errors stated:

> **ERROR:** for jekyll-serve  Cannot start service jekyll-serve: network
>   b52287167caf352c7a03c4e924aaf7d78e2bc372c703560c003acc758c013432 not
>   found
>   **ERROR:** Encountered errors while bring up the project.

`docker system prune` 
enabled me to begin using `docker-compose up` again.

More info here: https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/

Answer (score 16):

### Deleting the "network not found" in docker

Inspect the network which we are unable to delete

```
docker network inspect <id> or <name>
```

Disconnect the network

```
docker network disconnect -f <networkID> <endpointName> or <endpointId>
```

Delete unused networks

```
docker network prune
```

Comment: someone have tested?

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I automated this solution and trigger it each time i have a ghost network. Working very well.

Comment: to get this answer I have spent almost 4 hours finding out why it will occur and how to solve it.

Comment: I can confirm that this works.

Comment: Didn't work in my case, unfortunatelly

Comment: This would only work if the network actually existed, present in `docker network ls`. Otherwise a `disconnect` attempt will still return `network <id> not found`, and `docker network prune` will not fix the ghost network.

Answer (score 10):

I could not get rid of the networks by any of the methods in previous answers.

This is what worked for me.

```
systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: This workaround was in the original question BTW, albeit less explicitly.

Answer (score 7):

That sounds exactly like [this issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/30942).

Stack rm followed "too fast" by stack deploy would race for the creation/removal of networks, possibly other stack resources.

The issue is still open as of today ([docker/cli](https://github.com/docker/cli/issues/373)), but you could try the workaround suggested:

```
until [ -z "$(docker service ls --filter label=com.docker.stack.namespace=$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME -q)" ] || [ "$limit" -lt 0 ]; do
  sleep 1;
done

until [ -z "$(docker network ls --filter label=com.docker.stack.namespace=$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME -q)" ] || [ "$limit" -lt 0 ]; do
  sleep 1;
done
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem .. when I use this code in a script, it is stuck in an infinite loop as (at least) one network is _never_ removed.

Comment: Well... [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29293) is the same issue again, still open. They also suggested the restart of the daemon, did you do that before testing the script?

Comment: Also it says it takes a while to actually delete the network, can you try running it for a couple of minutes?

Comment: Yeah, as indicated in my question, restarting the daemon is my "hardfix", but it really seems kind of strange.

Comment: It ran for about 10 minutes and did not complete. When I run `docker network ls`, one of the networks is still visible, over 30 minutes after removing the stack. But I guess there seems to be no solution to the problem at the moment (based on the issues that you linked).

Answer (score 6):

None of the above worked for me. I've used the following docker-compose command to fix.

```bash
docker-compose up --force-recreate --remove-orphans
```

Answer (score 4):

To me it helped to use

```
docker network connect existingNetwork container
```

for all network failing containers, nothing else seemed to help to me, since they seemed to be connected as implied to a non existing network, here mentioned disconnecting them dindt help only re/connecting to existing, and removing network that non-existing ended up in an error "could not remove a non existing network" ofc

Answer (score 0):

old containers are still using old network. Probably you removed networks but forgot to rm old containers. Just remove old containers, create your network and build again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the experience I got and I think it might help.
Docker network is capable of doing bridging. In course told, a container can disconnect and connect from one to the other. If one disconnects from current and connect to the other, and the current disappear due to shutdown/network prune, the independent container will lose the connection. Later, when you try to start, only found "network not found" error.

The solution to this is start swarm/cluster (in my case I start with docker-compose up), disconnect the container (even it's yet up) from that network using force (-f). Connect back to that (different ID, but same name) network. Now you can successfully start it without "network not found" error.
So, the point is it maybe happens to see same name and different ID network.